# Magento2 - after installation: Setup starts again

Tags: magento2, installation, windows, docker

Today is my big Magento2 day and I run from one error into the next.
After some hours I was able to install Magento completly.

In the last step, it comes to "go to backend" "go to frontend".
1) Instead of my chosen URL m2.docker/ it has screwed my URL to m2.dockerL/ 
This is pretty strange.
2) The more worst problem: If I go to frontend, the installation mode comes up again!

It installed 100% with success page but I canÄt reach backend nor frontend because installation page comes up.

Any suggestions please?

Thank you!